# Missing the compiled messenger plugin for monotouch - mvvmcross

Tags: plugins, xamarin, mvvmcross, messenger

Attempting to use the latest compiled monotouch mvvmcross libraries.  Following N+9 but it seems there is a core version of messenger plugin but no monotouch version.  How do I fix it?  i.e. couldnt find this for touch: Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one.

The MvvmCross Messenger is a 'pure portable' plugin - it doesn't contain any platform specific extensions, just portable code.

The nuget installers take this into account automatically - as shown in the n=9 video and source code - http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com

You can read more about plugins - including about how to write and load them in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Comment: thanks again stuart...im using Xamarin Studio and so unable to get nuget working.  So I think your saying I can just use the standard portable version of Messenger into the clients?

Comment: If you are unable to get nuget working, you can reference the dll's manually to get it to work. I guess you would need Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.dll which you can get from here... https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Binaries

Comment: Thanks guys i simply utilised the portable class library version and then created another file in my bootstrap folder and hey presto it all works.